# google map style not working from snazzy

Tags: css, google-maps, styles

I'm following this [tutorial](https://snazzymaps.com/style/151/ultra-light-with-labels) to make style in my google map, but it doesn't work.

this my code

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=MY_API" type="text/javascript"></script>

if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

  var mapOptions = {
      // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
      zoom: 11,

      // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

      // How you would like to style the map.
      // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
      styles: [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}]
  };

    var  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
}
```

google maps shown like normal map, but i want to make style in map.how to achieve this ? 
i want to my google maps showing map like this picture
[image]

thanks.

Comment: what do you mean you want to make style in map?

Comment: style to make map display like picture. see edit

Comment: The v2 API doesn't support styled maps

Comment: how about v3 ? its support or no ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

Answer (score 0):

The v2 API doesn't support styled maps. To use the v3 API change the API include to remove the &v=2 (and while you're at it, change it to the [documented include](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API), be sure to add your API key).

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var mapOptions = {
    // How zoomed in you want the map to start at (always required)
    zoom: 11,

    // The latitude and longitude to center the map (always required)
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6700, -73.9400), // New York

    // How you would like to style the map.
    // This is where you would paste any style found on Snazzy Maps.
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#e9e9e9"
      }, {
        "lightness": 17
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }, {
        "lightness": 20
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }, {
        "lightness": 17
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }, {
        "lightness": 29
      }, {
        "weight": 0.2
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }, {
        "lightness": 18
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }, {
        "lightness": 16
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f5f5f5"
      }, {
        "lightness": 21
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi.park",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#dedede"
      }, {
        "lightness": 21
      }]
    }, {
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "color": "#ffffff"
      }, {
        "lightness": 16
      }]
    }, {
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "saturation": 36
      }, {
        "color": "#333333"
      }, {
        "lightness": 40
      }]
    }, {
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#f2f2f2"
      }, {
        "lightness": 19
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#fefefe"
      }, {
        "lightness": 20
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#fefefe"
      }, {
        "lightness": 17
      }, {
        "weight": 1.2
      }]
    }]
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem that I have fixed today.

Some of styles from [SnazzyMap](https://snazzymaps.com/) did work on my application, while some did not ([this one for example](https://snazzymaps.com/style/72543/assassins-creed-iv)). But all styles worked for the site [Map Style With Google](https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/).

I use Google Map API version 3.38.11 which is currently the last stable version. While  SnazzyMap uses version 3.39.6. But that was not the problem.

I’ve also tried with different browsers on my same computer, the behavior was the same.

Here is what I did and worked for me:

1. Open the Development panel in the navigator (Chrome or Firefox), then disable the HTTP cache (at the Console Parameters Panel).
2. Reload your application, having the panel opened.
3. Choose a style configuration that works on SnazzyMap and MapStyleWithGoogle but not with your application. Use it to update your current Google Map object : `myMap.setOptions({styles: myStyles})`
4. If the style is not applied and your map design is reset to default styles, then try the same style configuration but without the last item in the JSON array.
5. Continue #4 until the configuration is taken in account (It was the second try for me).
6. As strange as is seems, the first style configuration will work now. And even is you reload your application.

I cannot explain but it did work for me. I think the problem came from a kind of Google caching.